# How can I manually specify a parameter's generic type with a `TypeVar` in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, types, python-typing

I have some classes that use generic types by inheriting from `typing.Generic`. In methods of these classes, the `self` parameter retains the generic type of the object; for example, in `iter_1()` below, the type of `self` is inferred as `OuterBase[InnerBaseT]`.

How can I specify this type manually for a function parameter? I want to provide the parameter's type as `OuterBaseT` along with its generic type `InnerBaseT`. The reason I want to do this is so that in `iter_2()` below, the type of `item` in the scope of the `for` loop will not be `Any`, but `InnerBaseT`, or whatever custom `TypeVar` that I provide. (I know I can simply add a line `item: InnerBaseT` above the for loop, but this feels more like a workaround than a general solution.)

I am looking for something similar to the syntax in `iter_3()`. However, this way seems to ignore everything except the inner-most bracketed type, and just takes that as the type of the parameter (see comments).

I have scoured the `typing` docs and other SO questions to no avail. Is this possible? If not, why not—would implementing it in mypy somehow have strange consequences for type inference in other scenarios?

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, List, Iterable


InnerBaseT = TypeVar('InnerBaseT', bound='InnerBase')
OuterBaseT = TypeVar('OuterBaseT', bound='OuterBase')


class InnerBase: pass
class InnerDerived1(InnerBase): pass
class InnerDerived2(InnerBase): pass


class OuterBase(Generic[InnerBaseT]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items: List[InnerBaseT] = []

    def iter_1(self) -> Iterable:
        # Type of `self` is shown as `OuterBase[InnerBaseT]` (PyCharm with mypy=0.971, see screenshot)
        for item in self.items:
            # Type of `item` is correctly `InnerBaseT`
            yield item

    def iter_2(self) -> Iterable:
        def helper(outer_base: OuterBaseT) -> Iterable:
            for item in outer_base.items:
                # Type of `item` here is `Any`
                yield item

        yield from helper(self)

    def iter_3(self) -> Iterable:
        def helper(outer_base: OuterBaseT[InnerBaseT]) -> Iterable:
            # Type of `outer_base` is `InnerBaseT` (strange)
            for item in outer_base.items:
                yield item

        yield from helper(self)  # "Expected type 'InnerBaseT', got 'OuterBase[InnerBaseT]' instead"
```

Hovering over `self` (PyCharm with mypy=0.971) shows that the inferred type shows its corresponding generic `TypeVar`, which is basically what I want to manually specify:
[image: Hovering over self shows the type I want]

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal here, so to clarify: You want your IDE to understand that the `outer_base` parameter of the `helper` function has the same type as the `self` parameter of the `iter_3` function?

Comment: Well, not quite - I don't need it to dynamically follow the type of `self`. It's just that `self` has the type "format" I want, which is the class type **and a `TypeVar` for the parameter type's generic variable**, ex. `X[T]` instead of just `X`. The goal is to manually specify this for a parameter in a method or function. Seems like it must be possible given that the inferred type of `self` for methods takes this format.

Comment: So you just want `def helper(outer_base: OuterBase[InnerBase]):` then?

Comment: Wow, I guess that was all I needed (actually I needed `OuterBase[InnerBaseT]`). I was using `outer_base: OuterBaseT[InnerBaseT]` and for some reason didn't consider making the outer type the actual object name instead of the type variable. Thanks!

Comment: If you post as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I still don't understand your goal. I'm not entirely sure if it's wrong, but `OuterBase[InnerBaseT]` doesn't look right to me. Since the TypeVar isn't bound to a generic class and it only appears in the function once, what's the point of the TypeVar? As far as I can tell, that's functionally equivalent to `OuterBase[InnerBase]`, which in turn is equivalent to `OuterBase` (since `InnerBase` was already declared as the bound in the class definition anyway).

Comment: Fair point - I thought about what you said and created a situation that better shows the problem: https://gist.github.com/jacksonthall22/9a6ae5016637e1adfd03e30ac5de1b0c

Comment: There seems to be a bit of a disconnect between your goal (having correct type annotations for the `iter_X` methods) and the way you want to achieve that (making the type checker understand the type of `item` in the `helper` method). Strictly speaking, missing (parameter/return) annotations in functions are supposed to be treated as `Any`. So you *must* add a `-> Generator[InnerBaseT, Any, None]` annotation to every `iter_X` method. PyCharm is being nice by inferring the return type for you, but that is actually inconsistent with how python's type system works.

Comment: By the way, I was wrong about `OuterBase` being equivalent to `OuterBase[InnerBase]` - it's actually `OuterBase[Any]`. Also, in VSCode `iter_1`, `iter_2` and `iter_4` have their types inferred correctly (and the others always say "Unknown").

Comment: Actually, I take back what I said about PyCharm contradicting python's type system. Mypy also infers the return type of those methods (instead of treating them as `Any`). So honestly, I'm completely lost at this point.

Comment: Hmm, I asked this question thinking something was seriously wrong with my understanding of TypeVars and Generics but I guess this confirms my suspicion that it's a PyCharm problem if VSCode and Mypy both like `iter_1/2/4` - these are the only ones that should have the correct types. I have been confusing myself with this for a good while now, thanks for taking time to help!